# My embedded Python running inside "syslog-ng -Fevd" does not appear to receive signals, is that true?

Tags: python, signals, syslog-ng

I have a Python program running inside "syslog-ng -Fevd" OSE version 3.8 so I can develop quickly from the command line. My signal handler catches control-C (and I assume other signals) when run from the command line but not when inside of syslog-ng. Are signals known to be propagated to Python in syslog-ng? I am new to Python, did I make a mistake?

```
#Start of syslog-ng python config
python {

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    stopSubscription()

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGBUS, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGCLD, handler)

def stopSubscription():
    print "shutdown requested"
}; # end of syslog-ng block
```

From the command line (control-C) and also from inside PyCharm (stop button) I get

Signal handler called with signal 2
shutdown requested

but from syslog-ng, crickets.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in you Python code. You must import signal module in order to register your functions.

However, fixing your code won't solve your problem. If you register handlers in Python, it seems that signals won't be forwarded to neither Python nor the signal handler of syslog-ng.